# Constrained centroid of a triangle plus a semi-circle

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

An isosceles triangle $T$ has base $2r$ and altitude $h$. The base of $T$ coincides with a diameter a semicircular disk $D$ of radius $r$.

I have to find the relation that must hold between $r$ and $h$ so that the centroid of $T\cup D$ lies inside the triangle.

Without loss of generality, I assumed that the semicircle has its center at the origin and the isosceles triangle is right above the $x$-axis.

The answer is $h>r\sqrt{2}$  but I keep getting $\pi$ and I don't understand how $\pi$ is canceled.

Answer (score 0):

The centroid of $T$ is $(0, \frac13 h)$. The centroid of $D$ is $(0, -\frac{4r}{3\pi})$ (note the $\pi$ in the denominator). Therefore the centroid of $T \cup D$ is:

$$ C_x = \frac{\sum C_{i_x} A_i}{\sum A_i}, C_y = \frac{\sum C_{i_y} A_i}{\sum A_i} $$

which gives:

$$ C_x = 0 $$
$$ C_y = \frac{\left(\frac 13 h\right) hr + \left(\frac12 \pi r^2\right)\left(-\frac{4r}{3\pi}\right)}{hr + \frac12 \pi r^2} $$

and $C_y > 0$ only if $h > r\sqrt{2}$, as you state.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the centre of the half-disk is in the origin and the vertex of the triangle lies in $(0,h)$, we have that the centroid of the triangle lies in $\left(0,\frac{h}{3}\right)$ while the centroid of the half-disk lies in $\left(0,-\frac{4r}{3\pi}\right)$. Since the area of the triangle is $rh$ while the area of the half-disk is $\frac{\pi}{2}r^2$, we have that the centroid of $T\cup D$ lies above the $x$-axis iff:
$$\frac{h}{3}\cdot(rh)>\frac{4r}{3\pi}\cdot\left(\frac{\pi}{2}r^2\right)$$
i.e. iff $h> r\sqrt{2}$.